# Android Studio AVD dev/KVM is not found

Tags: android-studio, linux-mint, android-virtual-device

I'm trying to create an AVD, I get the error message:

> /dev/kvm is not found ; Enable VT-x in your BIOS security settings,
>   ensure that your Linux distro has working KVM module.

I go to the BIOS and enable the VT option. 
Then, I install KVM using [this tutorial](https://blog.flaunt7.com/install-kvm-linux-mint/).
All it's fine. But when i try :

```
kvm-ok
```

I get this message